# How to configure detach key-sequence like Docker's detachKeys using kubectl?

Tags: linux, docker

The default key sequence for detaching from a running container is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> in both Docker and Kubernetes.

For Docker (e.g. `docker run`), I can change this with either `--detach-keys` on the command line or `detachKeys` in ~/.docker/config.json.

I can't find anything similar for when running containers via kubectl. Is it similarly configurable?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't appear to be configurable at the moment. There's some issues (closed for inactivity) at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79110 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71765